# How do I indicate an en-dash while in math mode using LaTeX?

Tags: latex

There are four kinds of 'dashes' in LaTeX: hyphen,  en-dash(--), em-dash(---) and minus $-$. They are used for, respectively, hyphenation and joining words, indicating a range, punctuation, and a mathematical symbol.  My question is: how do I indicate an en-dash (range) in math mode? (as in `$S=1 to 2$`)? Do I have to drop out of math mode in the middle of the 'equation' (`$S=1$--$2$)`? Or is there a symbol I can use and stay in math mode? I tried `$S=1\--2$` but this gives me a minus, not a en-dash, and `$S=1--2$` gives two minuses.  My guess is I am going to have to drop out of math mode but maybe there is a way to do it without that.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

The simplest way is to use `$S=1\mbox{--}2$`.  If you already have `\usepackage{amsmath}` in your document's preamble, however, you're better off using `\text`: `$S=1\text{--}2$` because `\text` will adjust the size of the font when used in super- and subscripts: `$S_{1\text{--}2}=0$`.

An en dash used in math may easily be confused with a minus sign.  You may want to look at other techniques for indicating a range such as ellipses (`\ldots` for dots on the baseline [used between commas], or `\cdots` for centered dots [used between centered operators such as plus signs]) or using the bracket notation.  Some examples:

```
$S = \{1, 2, \ldots, n\}$ indicates an element in the set containing integers between 1 and $n$.
$S = [0, 1]$ indicates a real number between 0 and 1 (inclusive).
```

Comment: Agreed. Don't use an en dash where a minus sign could be expected. It will only confuse. Besides, what's wrong with simply "S = 1 to 2".

Comment: yes, I will probably go with 1 to 2 when I do the final edit of the paper, but having posed the problem it was interesting to find a solution. I often forget about \mbox. There are surely many other places it is useful. And I have now also learned about \text which I was not aware of before.

Comment: For what it's worth, I encountered a strange situation where this was useful, namely defining functions where the variable is unnamed: $(g \cdot f)(h\text{--}) = f(h\text{--}g)$. In my context, the right-hand side uses the action of a bimodule. Since $f, g, h$ are varying, it's actually clearer to use this strange notation. I definitely don't want a minus sign.

Answer (score 9):

You can use `\textrm` which does not depend on `\usepackage{amsmath}`.
Some examples:

```
$S=1\textrm{--}2$
$S_{1\textrm{--}2}=0$ % correctly changes the font size for subscript
$S_{1\textrm{2}2}=0$  % does not change the font size :(
```

Or maybe use `\textnormal` instead of `\textrm`.
See also [LaTeX: use \textnormal instead of \textrm (or \textsf) in math](http://stefaanlippens.net/textnormal/).

Comment: Better: `$S = \textrm{$1$--$2$}$`

Answer (score 4):

Well, you could use `$1\mbox{--}2$`, but I'd look at the list of math symbols in the [symbol list](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf). Hmm. I don't find one.

Answer (score 1):

Use the command `\leftrightline` in the package [MnSymbol](https://ctan.org/pkg/mnsymbol). I don't know if it's the length needed for your purposes, but hopefully it will do the trick.

Comment: Also: `\relbar`.